# Schema migrations using peewee to create new models

Tags: peewee, schema-migration

I really like how lightweight and simple `peewee` is for ORM. But now I am trying to implement schema migtations in the database and I feel `peewee` might be a bit limited on this aspect. From what I understand in the documentation, `peewee` migrations support altering schema on the exisiting models such as `add_not_null`, `add_column`. I am wondering is there any operations from `peewee` that can be used for adding or deleting models. Or if there is any other libaries that can help on this? Thanks in advance.

Pointing to `peewee` operations or 3rd party libaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peewee itself has facilities for creating and dropping tables:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    ...

# Create tables
database.create_tables([MyModel, OtherModel, ...])

# Drop tables
database.drop_tables([MyModel, OtherModel, ...])
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.create_tables

Comment: Thanks. But if I understand correctly it is not possible to add these operations to a migrator? Also wondering if there is an easy way to revert the migration operations in one migrator so we can roll back to the previous version of the schema.